# Access character and number

Tags: python, numpy

I have an input string, each element has a number and character which I want to access each element number and character separately as the following:

```
1h,1r,1r-2r,3r,1r # this is the line in the input file:
```

So I want to make an array includes only numbers as `x=[1,1,1,2,3,1]` numpy
and another array string as `s=[h,r,r,r,r,r]`

I also attach the code as the following:

```
import numpy as np

with open('dataa.dat', 'r') as f:
    input_data = f.readlines()
    input_data = [(d+' ')[:d.find('#')].rstrip() for d in input_data]

t_f  = input_data[0].split("-")
t_f2 = []

for elt in t_f:
    if "*" in elt:
        n, mult = elt.split("*")
        t_f2 = t_f2 + [int(n)] * int(mult)
    else:
        t_f2 += [x for x in elt.split(',')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use RegExp for something like this:

```
import re

data = "1h,1r,1r-2r,3r,1r"
matches = re.findall("(\d)([a-z])(?:([,-]|$))", data)
x = [int(match[0]) for match in matches]
s = [match[1] for match in matches]
print(x) # [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1]
print(s) # ['h', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r']
```

[<sup>Repl.it</sup>](https://replit.com/@esqew/GrandRelievedDifferences#main.py)